# Range input (slider) with markings for intermediate points

Tags: html, css, slider

I want a slider using HTML5 like this: [image]
where I can display the value. I have tried the below code:

```
<input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 step=1 list=tickmarks>
    <datalist id=tickmarks>
        <option value="0 to 20">0</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>60</option>
        <option>80</option>
        <option>100</option>
    </datalist>
```

But nothing seems to work. Any Idea?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can sort of achieve what you want by using the below code. What we are doing here is:

- Use a linear-gradient (repeating) to generate the lines at the required intervals
- Add the text using a pseudo-element and then give the required space in between them using the `word-spacing` property. For Chrome (Webkit browsers) the container is not required and the commented code in the sample is alone enough but Firefox requires to container. I think behavior in FF is the correct one because `input` elements generally aren't expected to support pseudo-elements and hence it is better to retain the container to be future-proof

**Points to note:**

- This sample is tested on Chrome (44.0.2376.0 dev-m, 42.0.2311.90 m), Firefox (36.0.4), Internet Explorer 11 and Opera 28.
- I assume that the usage of `repeating-linear-gradient` or `linear-gradient` should not be an issue.

**Browser Support :**

- For Range Input - Chrome  5+, Firefox 23+, IE 10+, Safari 3.1+, Opera 9+
- For Repeating Gradient - Chrome 10+ (-webkit prefix), Firefox 3.6+ (-moz prefix), IE 10+, Safari 5.1, Opera 11.6.

```css
input[type='range'] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #777, #777 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #777, #777 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #777, #777 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: 122px 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #777;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #777;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #EEE;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 210px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #777;
  color: #777;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background: #EEE;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #EEE;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/*input[type='range']:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '20 40 60 80';
  padding: 25px 4035px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}*/

.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: #777;
  content: '20 40 60 80';
  padding: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Just for demo */

output{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #777;
}
output:before{
  content:"Selected Value: ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
body {
  font-family: Calibri, Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" list="tickmarks" id="rangeInput" oninput="output.value = rangeInput.value">
  <datalist id="tickmarks">
    <option value="0 to 20">0</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>60</option>
    <option>80</option>
    <option>100</option>
  </datalist>
  <output id="output" for="rangeInput">50</output> <!-- Just to display selected value -->
</div>
```

[**Demo on Codepen**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/BNyzvj/)

Comment: There seriously isn't an easier way to do this?

Comment: Nope, no other easier way as far as I am aware @JustinSmith

Comment: @Harry can we put intervals wherever we want? I am using the range input for youtube progress bar and want to mark for different time duration. any work around on how to achieve this ? Please help

Comment: @Harry Although already upvoted, I wanted add that I think your answer is beautiful - and just what I was thinking/searching about/for. :-)

Comment: This would be a great JS component if anyone could encapsulate that.

Comment: For anyone still searching, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983699) might be of interest. It uses a trick by using justify content to calculate word spacing.