# range input indicator for position 0, and datalist

Tags: html

I have a range input that goes from a negative to a positive and I want to indicate the position 0.

what I do at the moment is indicating it with datalist:

```html
 <input  type=range min=-4830 max=2000 value=50 id=fader step=1 list="numbers" />
    <datalist id="numbers">
      <option>0</option>
    </datalist>
```

But the problem is that it stays stuck to the 0 when I change cursor. And also it's not enough visible.

how can I do? And can I add a "0" on top of the tick to indicate position of it? change its css?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about indicating the selected value?

```
<input id='rangeInput' type=range min=-4830 max=5000 value=50 step=1 list="numbers" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" />
<output id="amount" name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
<datalist id="numbers">
<option>0</option>
</datalist>
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/b30fa999/2/)

**EDIT**

Updated code, combined with yours. Should be clear enough to mark and show value I think.

**EDIT 2**

A simple solution could be something like this:

HTML:

```html
<div id="cont">
<span id="zero">0</span>
<input id='rangeInput' type=range min=-4830 max=5000 value=50 step=1 list="numbers" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" />
<datalist id="numbers">
<option>0</option>
</datalist>
</div>
<output id="amount" name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
```

CSS:

```css
#cont {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
#zero {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    color: lightgray;
}

#rangeInput {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 410px;
}
```

The `zero` will be in the middle of the `cont` `<div>` element. You can try moving it around. I increased width, because the range is big.

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/b30fa999/7/)

Comment: No because I really need an indicator to show where the 0 is , because the min and max and original value are chosen randomly

Comment: Is a combined solution better?

Comment: I just want the tick to be more visible like on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873586

Comment: In your case could be simpler since you only need one marker. See updated example.