# how can I style the ticks on a range input?

Tags: html, css

I'm using range inputs in my questionnaire and I want to make the lines bolder.  So far the code I have is

```
<input type="range" id="q8a1" name="#" min="1" max="10" list="input01" value="1" step="1" style="width:100%; />

<datalist id="input01">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </datalist>
```

I tried using inline CSS to add a border attribute and a few other things but nothing worked.  I gooogled everything I could think of revolving around this and researched pseudo classes to see if there's a way to style it the same way they have them to style the thumb and rail for the range input but I just couldn't find anything.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: line of range inputs?

Comment: My information maybe outdated but I think it is not possible to directly style the ticks and you'd need to use some custom styling like in my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873586/range-input-slider-with-markings-for-intermediate-points/29875717#29875717.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ticks for type="range" HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612700/ticks-for-type-range-html-input)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `list="tickmarks"` attribute

More info [here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range), and as of December 2, 2017, this is still not supported.