# range slider with custom range steps ( a - b- c- d - .. - z)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize, rangeslider

I need a range slider recommendation with possibility to customize range steps.

For example my range steps should be as:

```
a - b - c - d
```

with associated values of (0, 1, 2, 3). I need to be able to select minimum and maximum value for the range.

I did some Googling but couldn't find any.

Top two range sliders are (as it seems to me at least): [rangeslider](http://rangeslider.js.org/) and [nouislider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) but I can't figure out how to tweak any of them to do what I need.

I'm using materializecss and jQuery for my app so I would prefer solutions based upon these libraries but any suggestion is appreciated as it seems to me that this won't be an easy task.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a normal range element and map the numbers to letters?

Comment: Hm, could you point me to some example. I might have missed something basic here. Also, I need min and max values here. Will update my question.

Comment: Check my answer below for a working example.

Comment: I believe the behavior of the tickers change from browser to browser.

Comment: This seems like it's going to be one fun task... I hoped something like this already exists, guess not. I will post my solution when I find one, hopefully soon.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29875717/4543207) may give you a start up.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a normal range element and map the numbers to letters?

```js
var rng = document.getElementById("rng");
var ro = document.getElementById("rngOutput");
var myRange = ["a","b","c","d"];

function updateRange(){
   ro.textContent = myRange[parseInt(rng.value, 10)];
   console.log("Selected value is: " + myRange[parseInt(rng.value, 10)] + ", Associated value is: " + rng.value);
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateRange);
rng.addEventListener("input", updateRange);
```

```html
<input type="range" id="rng" min="0" max="3" value="0"><span id="rngOutput"></span>
```

Comment: This make sense (at least on first view, my js is not very good) but how do I use it with upper and lower bound?

Comment: You can set the upper and lower numeric values in the HTML. The array with the letters can be declared once, with all the letters you may want.