# Slider not showing ticks

Tags: html, css, dom, input, slider

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv2h07vk/3/) to explain my issue.

when removing the `-webkit-appearance: none;` the vertical lines appear but the circle reset to the standard one, how can I fix it? and possibly edit those ticks in css?

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873586/range-input-slider-with-markings-for-intermediate-points

Comment: perhaps, but i can't make it precise with width:100%, after a while it gets offset

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dv2h07vk/9/ it is not really working like this, any idea?