# HTML5 Input type Range with min value slider, max value slider, and ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to implement HTML5 input type Range

```
<input type="range"  min="0" max="100" step="10"  value="40" />
```

Now i want to show ticks on steps just like on image attached. Is it possible ? Is there any way ?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Which ticks and how they relate to step ?

Comment: Show us what you've tried? What is expected output?

Comment: You want what now? Please explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail.

Comment: I think you are looking for <input type="number"  min="0" max="100" step="10"  value="40" />.

Comment: Take a look at [this Collection of pens](http://codepen.io/collection/DgYaMj/) created buy Ana Tudor

Comment: @ShoaibKonnur no I am looking for slider-

Comment: @Mairaj please check Image

Comment: @George please check image . this is what i want to achive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement this with HTML5's input type `Range` is not possible because it accept only one input

> you can achieve this by using JQUERY slider check this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "₹" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - ₹" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "₹" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - ₹" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was exactly look for this

Comment: There are no ticks...the OP asked for Ticks.

Comment: @vsync  well it show me the value on slide. I can work with it :)

Answer (score 4):

I've made you a [simple example](http://jsbin.com/zurisiz/1/edit?html,css,output) which will show you how to get what you want.

This code will generate ticks for you, and you can change the amount of ticks and their style accordingly. You **should** generate the HTML automatically.

```css
.rangeWrap {
  width: 40%;
}
.rangeWrap input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.rangeWrap .ticks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 6px;
  margin: -1.5em 5px 0 6px;
  font: 10px Arial;
  counter-reset: count -1;
}
.rangeWrap .ticks > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: silver;
  counter-increment: count 1;
}
.rangeWrap .ticks > div:nth-child(5n - 4) {
  height: 200%;
}
.rangeWrap .ticks > div:nth-child(5n - 4)::before {
  display: block;
  content: counter(count,decimal);
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
  <div class='rangeWrap'>
    <input type="range"  min="0" max="100" step="10"  value="40" />
    <div class='ticks'>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this sol. this could be the one, but i got more accurate what i was looking for. I accepted that answer. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @AsifAhmad - no problem. but the title of this question clearly is asking for **ticks** and I've spend time creating you code which does what you asked for.. you asked to show ticks. I showed ticks :) it's not really fair for me to spend my time if you wanted a multirange all this time.

Comment: I want both n I gona make a hybrid of these two :)

Answer (score 3):

I've found **exactly** what you are after:

https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See Woodrow Barlow's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26613443/6449386). I'll summarize here:

Internet Explorer (of all things) support this out of the box when you supply the step attribute, like in your question:

```
<input type="range"  min="0" max="100" step="10"  value="40" />
```

For other browsers, various workarounds are needed, with possible side-effects. In Chrome and Safari, you can use a datalist to provide the steps:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" list="steplist">
<datalist id="steplist">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>75</option>
    <option>100</option>
</datalist>
```

In Firefox, the solution is even more elaborate, and includes custom css - [see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofhjxef0/).

Comment: this suppose to be in comment section

Answer (score 0):

Doing this natively / polyfilled:

- For the tick marks: Woodrow Barlow's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26613443/1241736) (summarized in @Lagostra's on this question) is the native solution, but it currently isn't very customizable
- For the double sliders: The `[type="range"]` spec includes a `multiple` attribute, which is supposed to do exactly this… but as of this writing no browsers support it. The http://leaverou.github.io/multirange/ polyfill works for all browsers that support CSS variables.