# How to merge two inputs by type=range in ReactJs to make a slider?

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON file called by fetch() request.I have two input by type=range .Is it possible to make a HTML5 slider with two input values in react?I'd like to make the double slider , but if I draw two elements on top of one another, only the top one is accepting mouse clicks.Actually
I do not want to use any external library in React to make the slider.

```
 class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        data: [],
        library:null,
            .
            .
            .

        };
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'get',
    },)
     .then(response => response.text())
     .then(text => {
        .
        .
        .
        .
     }).catch(error => console.error(error))
     }
      .
      .
      .
      .
 // handle render of library
 renderLibrary = () => {
  const { library } = this.state;
  return library.sort((a,b)=>a.total - b.total).map((item, i) => (
   <div className="item">
      {item._id}
      .
      .
      .
   </div>
   ))
 }
render() {
const { library} = this.state;
return (
    <div>    
        <input type="range" min="12" max="24" defaultValue="24" step="1" className="exitTimeSecond" />
        <input type="range" min="0" max="11" defaultValue="0" step="1" className="exitTimeFirst" />
       {this.renderLibrary()}
       </div>
       )
       }  
     }
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Edite :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<style>
  .price-slider{ position: relative; width: 400px; margin: 0 auto 20px; height: 35px; text-align: center;}
  .price-slider input{pointer-events: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 15px; width: 100%; outline: none; height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-radius: 8px;}
 .price-slider input::-webkit-slider-thumb{pointer-events: all; position: relative; z-index: 1; outline: 0; height: 24px; widows: 24px; border-radius: 12px; background-color: white; border: 2px solid black; -webkit-appearance: none;}
</style>
<body>
<div  id="container"></div>
<script src="/js/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="/js/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="/js/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="/js/react.paging.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    class Hello extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
         val1:0,
         val2:100
        }
      }
componentDidMount() {
 this.sliders=
 document.querySelectorAll(".price-slider input");
}
updatePriceLabels = (e, slider) => {
console.log('ok')
let val1,val2;
if(slider==='one'){
    val1=e.target.value;
    val2=this.state.val2;
}else if(slider==='two'){
    val1=this.state.val1;
    val2=e.target.value;
}

if(val1 >= val2){
    this.setState({
     val1 :val2-3,
     val2:val2
    });
    return;
  }else if(val2<=val1){
    this.setState({
     val1:val1+3,
     val2:val1
    });
    return;
  }else{
    this.setState({
        val1:val1,
        val2:val2
    });
   }
 console.log(this.sliders)
if(val1 >0 || val2 < 99){
    this.sliders[0].style.background=
    this.sliders[1].style.background="-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0,100% 0, color-stop(0, white), color-stop(" + (val1 / 100) + ", white),color-stop(" + (val1 / 100) + ", #f0f0f0), color-stop(" + (val2 / 100) + ", #f0f0f0), color-stop(" + (val2 / 100) + ", white))";
}else{
    this.sliders[0].style.background=
    this.sliders[1].style.background='';
    }
}
render(){
 return(
     <div className="price-slider">
     <input value={this.state.val1} min="0" defaultValue="0" max="100" step="0.5" type="range" onChange={(e)=>this.updatePriceLabels(e,'one')} />
     <input value={this.state.val2} min="0" defaultValue="100" max="100" step="0.5" type="range" onChange={(e)=>this.updatePriceLabels(e,'two')} />
     </div>
  )
 }

 }
  ReactDOM.render(
     <Hello name="World" />,
     document.getElementById('container')
 );
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found online someone who did it, seems like what you're trying to do is quite hacky: http://giacomoballi.com/css-range-double-slider/#.XLQhgOszbMU
Here is another example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42391098/1871891.

You can build a less hacky version by yourself and draw inspiration on how it was built from people who have built it in the past, like https://github.com/joris-calvat/react-dual-range-slider/blob/master/src/components/react-dual-range-slider.jsx. Or a range of other ones out there.

Anyway, I created a fiddle for you based on Giacomo Balli -Found at http://giacomoballi.com/css-range-double-slider/#.XLQtueszbMV via @BigBalli:

https://jsfiddle.net/rockyhuber/b8g7scm0/

You can perfect the logic. It was really quickly thrown together. Hope this helps.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

constructor() {
super();
    this.state = { 
        val1: 0,
    val2: 100
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
this.sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".price-slider input");
}

updatePriceLabels = (e, slider) => { 

    let val1, val2;

  if (slider === 'one') {
    val1 = parseInt(e.target.value);
    val2 = parseInt(this.state.val2);    

    if (val1 >= val2 && val2 < 97) { 
      this.setState({
        val1: val1,
        val2: val2 + 3
      });
    }  else if (val1 >= 97) { 
      this.setState({
        val1: 97,
        val2: 100
      });
    } else if (val1 <= val2) { 
      this.setState({
        val1: val1,
        val2: val2
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        val1: val1,
        val2: val2
      });
    }
  } else if (slider === 'two') {
    val1 = parseInt(this.state.val1);
    val2 = parseInt(e.target.value);
    if (val2 <= val1 && val1 < 3) { 
      this.setState({
        val1: 0,
        val2: val1 + 3
      });
    } else if (val2 <= 3) { 
      this.setState({
        val1: 0,
        val2: 3
      });
    } else if (val2 <= val1) { 
      this.setState({
        val1: val2 - 3,
        val2: val2
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        val1: val1,
        val2: val2
      });
    }
  }


  console.log(this.sliders)
  if (val1 > 0 || val2 < 99) { 
    this.sliders[0].style.background = this.sliders[1].style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0,100% 0, color-stop(0, white), color-stop(" + (val1 / 100) + ", white),color-stop(" + (val1 / 100) + ", #f0f0f0), color-stop(" + (val2 / 100) + ", #f0f0f0), color-stop(" + (val2 / 100) + ", white))"; 
  } else { 
    this.sliders[0].style.background = this.sliders[1].style.background = ''; } 
}

  render() {
        return (
    <div className="price-slider">
      <input value={this.state.val1} min="0" max="100" step="0.5" type="range" onChange={(e) => this.updatePriceLabels(e, 'one')}></input>
      <input value={this.state.val2} min="0" max="100" step="0.5" type="range" onChange={(e) => this.updatePriceLabels(e, 'two')}></input>
    </div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Thanks @user1871891 for your answer. But I don not know why it does not work. I put `console.log('ok')` in `updatePriceLabels` function but did not show anything.

Comment: I just did an update to the jsfiddle as well, so it should work better now.

Comment: No @user1871891.Fiddle is not be opened for me!I could not see it!

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it is not working. It is public so you should have access to it.

Comment: @@user1871891. I added new code in **Edit** part of my code. It is the same as your code , but nothing happens and it does not work? why?

Comment: Is your html <div id="container"></div>?

Comment: Yes @user1871891.

Comment: If you do a fiddle with your code then I may be able to help better. But from my end and the fiddle I attached above, it works fine.

Comment: Your code works find too. See attached fiddle below: https://jsfiddle.net/rockyhuber/dq4pezL1/1/

Comment: Hi @user1871891. I found the problem. It is because of `pointer-events: none;` that does not work in Mozilla and IE browser.

Comment: I am searching for finding a solution But has not been found yet!

Comment: Not sure, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events. It says that it does work on those browsers so a bit confusing.