# How to create a scientific HTML slider with input type="range"

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-input

I need to create a scientific input slider. More precisely:

- n ticks, example: no matter the range (0 - 200, 1 - 11, etc.), I want 11 ticks covering the whole range
- the number value label below each tick
- no "glue" attraction effect when the slider cursor is near a tick

Mockup:

[image]

Note:

- this is not a duplicate of [Ticks for type="range" HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612700/ticks-for-type-range-html-input) because of these 3 points.
- browser support: at least Chrome

The following code produces a HTML slider with ticks, and it works. However, it fails both the 2nd and 3rd criteria above.

```css
input { width: 400px; }
```

```html
<input type=range min=0 max=200 value=0 step=1 list=tickmarks>
<datalist id=tickmarks>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>60</option>
    <option>80</option>
    <option>100</option>
    <option>120</option>
    <option>140</option>
    <option>160</option>
    <option>180</option>
    <option>200</option>
 </datalist>
```

Is there an attribute for an HTML `<input type="range">` to enable these "number-labelled" ticks?

Is an implementation that satisfies all three criteria possible?

Comment: This feels like a web component waiting to happen, but I don't think browsers do this natively.

Comment: According to the WHATWG spec, browsers _should_ respect\ `<option label="0">` for the tickmarks, but it doesn't look like any of them do.

Comment: this is not supported by default, i have a solution but i used some css and extra html markup to achieve it, since the question has been closed i can't add my answer

Comment: @mmh4all Great, can you share in a JSfiddle ? I'll vote to reopen the question (you can too).

Comment: Note about moderation: "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving": the question now contains three *precise* conditions to make a scientific application slider, can we reopen?

Comment: @Basj here is the jsFiddle i hope you can see the code, https://jsfiddle.net/b8dqp3w0/

Comment: @mmh4all Thanks but we cannot drag and drop more than a few pixels. There is something that prevents the drag n drop.

Comment: December last year I created [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/Expxwwo) based on another SO question, maybe it will give you some alternative to toy with. In the remainder of the CSS you will find my solution for your issue (search for *SO75802357*). Not posted as an answer as the glue effect is not solved...

Comment: @RenevanderLende Nice solution! Please post it as an answer, it is already very helpful! (You achieved to align perfectly the 0 and 200 ticks on the slider position, which is difficult).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Lajos Arpad's answer indicates, it's best to avoid using `datalist` as your requirements go beyond what it's capable of. You'll need to manually create the ticks with number values.

The following code uses a HTML layout similar to the original code in your question, with styling to suit. Note that the width is set on a parent element, and if the parent is too small then the tick numbers will wrap to a new line. To counter this you may need to decrease the tick number font size.

To get the ticks lining up properly across all major browsers it is perhaps better to style the slider so it looks identical across browsers. Styles targeting Chrome- and Firefox-specific pseudo-elements for range sliders are included. The result should look the same across all Chromium and Mozilla based browsers.

Note that a truly cross-browser method of filling in the range slider, as shown in the question, can only be achieved with JavaScript. The JavaScript here is basically copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57153340/1427563)

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input input")
input.addEventListener( 'input', function() {
    const value = (this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100;
    this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, #35b0f2 0%, #35b0f2 ' + value + '%, #ccc ' + value + '%, #ccc 100%)';
} );
```

```css
#input {
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#input span {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px -5px 0 -5px;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    user-select: none;
}
#input span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: -12px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#input input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 99px;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 7px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#input input::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 99px;
    background: #35b0f2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#input input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: none
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #35b0f2;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="input">
    <input type=range min=0 max=200 value=0 step=1>
    <span>0</span>
    <span>20</span>
    <span>40</span>
    <span>60</span>
    <span>80</span>
    <span>100</span>
    <span>120</span>
    <span>140</span>
    <span>160</span>
    <span>180</span>
    <span>200</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @jla for your answer! It is perfect on Chrome, on Firefox, the "0" and the "200" ticks are not perfectly aligned on the slider. Do you think there is a possible version working for main browsers, without having to do pixel adjustment manually?

Comment: @Basj updated answer so that the input is styled the same across all major browsers; this should fix the tick alignment issues

Comment: Now pixel-perfect on both Chrome and Firefox!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `datalist` with a list of `option`, but it will require you to add `label` texts as the `value` will not be used as tickmark values.

**generic setup** ([MDN: input type="range", Adding tick marks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#adding_tick_marks))

```html
    <input type="range" list="tickmark-list">
    <datalist id="tickmark-list">
        <option value=1 label="1"/>
        <option value=N label="N"/>
    </datalist>
```

For the labels you have two options:

**option 1**: use `label` with text

```html
<option value="1" label="tickmark-value-1"/>
<option value="N" label="tickmark-value-N"/>
```

**option 2**: use an *option text*

```html
<option value="1">tickmark-value-1</option>
<option value="N">tickmark-value-N</option>
```

When using both a `label` text and *option text*, the latter will be ignored. For the snippet I used *option 1*.

**tickmarks**

- `input type="range"` and `datalist` must have equal `width`. In the snippet I used *CSS custom property* `--slider-width: 100%` to set the width of either element.
- `datalist` as Flexbox row container with `justify-content: space-between` is perfectly suited to distribute the tickmark labels. It pushes the outer labels to their respective parent left and right margins, while evenly distributing the rest of the labels over the remaining space.
- For even distribution of tickmark texts it is best to give them all a `width` equal to the largest text. In the snippet I took the width of label `200`.
- To center the label text below the tickmarks use `text-align: center`.
- The tickmarks are default inserted by the range slider itself and does not require any extra code.

Depending on label texts used some fiddling with `margin/padding` of `option:first-child` and/or `option:last-child` might be required.

**Bonus** in the snippet I added class `.vertical` to show how you can use `flex-direction: column` and `writing-mode: vertical-lr` to easily get 90 degree rotated tickmark labels.

**UPDATE**

As initially commented the above method does not solve the 'glue' effect caused by the `datalist` tickmarks in Firefox browsers. Additionally, Firefox opens an `option` select list upon second click at a tickmark, treating a `datalist` as a `select`. While Firefox specific behavior and probably known/preferred by users, it may be unwanted for a site.

However, after investigation, it appears the forementioned behavior is very hard, if not impossible, to disable. One could opt to create a fully custom range slider with Javascript, but that may prove to be overkill: create a workaround for a single browser, disabling behavior that may or may not be changed in the future.

Tried methods **that fail:**

- `datalist,option { pointer-events: none }`
- `<option disabled />` works, but removes tickmark
- `<datalist type="range" autocomplete="off">`
- `<input type="range" autocomplete="off">`
- `<option autocomplete="off">`
- `<option label=".."/>` without `value=".."`
- `<option value="..">..</option>` text instead of `label`
- embed `<input type="range">` in a `<form>` with all elements `autocomplete="off"`
- Disable autocomplete history in browser Privacy Settings

```css
:root  { --slider-width: 100% }

input, datalist  {
    width: var(--slider-width);
}

datalist {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

option {
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.78rem; /* ~width of label '200' */
}

.vertical {
    flex-direction: column;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
input[list="tickmarks2"] { margin: 0 }

.vertical option { text-align: right; width: 1.5rem }
```

```html
<div id="SO75802357">
    <input type=range min=0 max=200 value=0 step=1 list="tickmarks1">
    <datalist id="tickmarks1">
        <option value=0   label="0"  />
        <option value=20  label="20" />
        <option value=40  label="40" />
        <option value=60  label="60" />
        <option value=80  label="80" />
        <option value=100 label="100"/>
        <option value=120 label="120"/>
        <option value=140 label="140"/>
        <option value=160 label="160"/>
        <option value=180 label="180"/>
        <option value=200 label="200"/>
    </datalist>
    <br><br>
    <input type=range min=0 max=200 value=0 step=1 list="tickmarks2">
    <datalist id="tickmarks2" class="vertical">
        <option value=0   label="0"  />
        <option value=20  label="20" />
        <option value=40  label="40" />
        <option value=60  label="60" />
        <option value=80  label="80" />
        <option value=100 label="100"/>
        <option value=120 label="120"/>
        <option value=140 label="140"/>
        <option value=160 label="160"/>
        <option value=180 label="180"/>
        <option value=200 label="200"/>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Minor thing: there is still the "glue" attraction effect near the ticks. Also on Firefox, a dropdown list opens sometimes when clicking on the slider's circle.

Comment: @Basj I added an update just before the snippet, taking my time to test a few things...

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to dynamically create a scale. There are many details to consider, such as steps. You can start here:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.range').forEach(el => {
  const input = el.querySelector('input');
  if(!input){
    return;
  }
  const min = Number(input.min) || 0;
  const step = Number(input.step) || 1;
  const max = Number(input.max);
  let ticks = Number(input.dataset.ticks);
  if(!max || !ticks || step !== 1 ){
    return;
  }
  if(ticks > max - min ){
    ticks = max - min + 1;
  }
  ticks--;
  let increment = (max - min) / ticks;
  let value = min;
  let html = '';
  for(let i = 0; i <= ticks; i++ ){
    html += `<div class="range-tick">${value.toFixed()}</div>`
    value += increment;
  }
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="range-ticks">${html}</div>`);
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.range {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  --thumb-size: 12px;
  --track-size: 2px;
  --track-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: calc(var(--thumb-size) / 2);
}
.range input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
}
.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: var(--thumb-size);
  height: var(--thumb-size);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: calc(var(--thumb-size) / -2 + var(--track-size) / 2);
}
.range input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: var(--track-size);
  background-color: var(--track-color);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.range-ticks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.range-tick {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: var(--thumb-size);
}
.range-tick:before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: var(--track-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" step="1" data-ticks="11" oninput="output.value = this.value">
</div>
<output id="output">0</output>
```

Comment: Nice solution, perfect on Chrome! (a little off in Firefox, but it's still a nice solution!)

Comment: Thanks! But this is only a base, a starting point for starting implementation, because, as I say, different nuances must be taken into account. I wish you success in the implementation of an interesting task!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by putting a div below your range that you divide into sections. The code below is just a proof-of-concept, which already works, but when you actually integrate it into your project, you will need to make it reusable and adjustable.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let div = document.getElementById("ranger-div");
    let html = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 200; i += 20) {
        html.push(`<div><div style="with:100%;">|</div>${i}</div>`);
    }
    div.innerHTML = html.join("");
});
```

```css
.ranger { width: 400px; }
#ranger-div {display: inline-flex; width: 440px;}
#ranger-div > div {
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input class="ranger" type=range min=0 max=200 value=0 step=1>
<div id="ranger-div"></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution @LajosArpad, completely avoiding the `datalist`, that's probably the best solution! Small thing: when the slider is on 0, the circle is not aligned on the "0" trick. Do you think there is a way to improve this, independently from the browser slider rendering? (The look is different from one browser to another)

Comment: @Basj yes, it's possible, I would approach that problem by playing around with the second div until I find out how it is matching. Then I would try it with different browsers and see whether the solution works well. If not, then you may need separate solutions for separate browsers. In our case I have been playing around with it for a bit and when it was good-enough for the purpose of a proof-of-concept, I have sent in my answer. This can be polished further, of course. Maybe some margin-left of a few pixels and reducing the width accordingly would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```js
class ScientificInput extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.step = "any";
    this.ticks = 11;
    this.canvasHeight = 24;
  }

  createSvgElement(elementName) {
    let element = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      elementName
    );
    return element;
  }

  createTickLines(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    let tickColor = this.getAttribute("tColor");
    let newLine = this.createSvgElement("line");
    newLine.setAttribute("x1", x1);
    newLine.setAttribute("y1", y1);
    newLine.setAttribute("x2", x2);
    newLine.setAttribute("y2", y2);
    if (tickColor) {
      newLine.setAttribute("stroke", tickColor);
    } else {
      newLine.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
    }
    return newLine;
  }

  createTickNumbers(txt, x, y) {
    let numberColor = this.getAttribute("nColor");
    let newText = this.createSvgElement("text");
    newText.setAttribute("font-size", "12px");
    if (txt < 1 && txt !== 0) {
      txt = parseFloat(txt.toFixed(4));
      txt = txt.toExponential();
    }
    if (txt > 1000) {
      txt = txt.toExponential();
    }

    if (numberColor) {
      newText.setAttribute("fill", numberColor);
    }

    newText.textContent = txt;
    newText.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
    newText.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
    return newText;
  }

  drawTicks(svg) {
    this.textNodes = [];
    const step = (this.max - this.min) / 10;
    let currentWidth = parseFloat(
      getComputedStyle(this).width.replace("px", "")
    );
    const factor = (currentWidth - 16) / (this.max - this.min);
    for (let tick = 0; tick < 11; tick++) {
      const horizontalOffset = Math.ceil(tick * step * factor + 8);
      const line = this.createTickLines(
        horizontalOffset,
        0,
        horizontalOffset,
        5
      );
      svg.append(line);
      const text = this.createTickNumbers(
        tick * step + this.min,
        horizontalOffset,
        20
      );
      svg.append(text);
      this.textNodes.push(text);
    }
  }

  adjustTextPosition() {
    this.textNodes.forEach((e, i) => {
      const textWidth = Math.round(e.getBBox().width);
      if (i === 0) {
        e.setAttribute("transform", `translate(-${5} 0)`);
      } else if (i === 10) {
        e.setAttribute("transform", `translate(-${textWidth - 5} 0)`);
      } else {
        e.setAttribute("transform", `translate(-${textWidth / 2} 0)`);
      }
    });
  }

  createContainer() {
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.setAttribute("id", "container");
    container.style.width = "100%";
    container.style.display = "flex";
    container.style.flexFlow = "column";
    return container;
  }

  createSvg() {
    let svg = this.createSvgElement("svg");
    svg.setAttributeNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
      "xmlns:xlink",
      "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    );
    svg.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    svg.setAttribute("height", this.canvasHeight);
    return svg;
  }

  createRange() {
    const range = document.createElement("input");
    range.type = "range";
    range.min = this.min;
    range.max = this.max;
    range.step = this.step;
    range.style.margin = "0";
    range.style.width = "100%";
    range.addEventListener("change", (e) => console.log(e.target.value));
    return range;
  }

  render() {
    this.width = parseFloat(this.getAttribute("width"));
    this.min = parseFloat(this.getAttribute("min"));
    this.max = parseFloat(this.getAttribute("max"));

    this.style.width = this.width + "px";

    // create a container
    this.container = this.createContainer();

    // create and set input control
    const range = this.createRange();

    // create a svg
    this.svg = this.createSvg();

    // draw the ticks on the canvas
    this.drawTicks(this.svg);

    // append the input to container
    this.container.append(range);

    // append the svg to container
    this.container.append(this.svg);

    // append the container to this instance
    this.append(this.container);

    // center the numbers
    this.adjustTextPosition();

    new ResizeObserver(() => {
      this.svg.remove();
      this.svg = this.createSvg();
      this.drawTicks(this.svg);
      this.container.append(this.svg);
      this.adjustTextPosition();
    }).observe(this.container);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
  }
}

customElements.define("scientific-input", ScientificInput, {
  extends: "div"
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.s-input {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0375ff;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: #0375ff;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="s-input" is="scientific-input" min="0" max="10" width="300" tColor="forestGreen" nColor="hotPink"></div>
<div class="s-input" is="scientific-input" min="0" max="100" width="400" tColor="darkOrange" nColor="forestGreen"></div>
<div class="s-input" is="scientific-input" min="100" max="700" width="500"></div>
<div class="s-input" is="scientific-input" min="0" max="10000" width="500"></div>
<div class="s-input" is="scientific-input" min="0" max="0.007" width="500" ></div>
```

I have created another solution for this one with web component, with it you have far more control and customization.

[image: Edit hungry-surf-xuv0et]

Comment: Works on Chrome, but slightly off on Firefox (round slider position not aligned on the ticks for "0" and "end").

Comment: @Basj these two cases were special, I had to do that way to keep them inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

According to me and as everyone suggested in this answer It is recommended to not use `datalist` if your needs exceed its capabilities. Instead, you should manually create the ticks with numerical values.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#rangeSelector input");
const updateRangeSelector = () => {
  const value = (input.value - input.min) / (input.max - input.min) * 100;
  input.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0500ff 0%, #3549f2 ${value}%, #ccc ${value}%, #ccc 100%)`;
};
input.addEventListener('input', updateRangeSelector);
```

```css
#rangeSelector {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#rangeSelector input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 99px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 7px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#rangeSelector input::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background: #0500ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rangeSelector input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: none border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #0500ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#rangeSelector span {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px -5px 0 -5px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .85em;
  user-select: none;
}

#rangeSelector span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: -12px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="rangeSelector">
  <input type=range min=0 max=200 value=0 step=1 list=tickmarks>
  <span>0</span>
  <span>20</span>
  <span>40</span>
  <span>60</span>
  <span>80</span>
  <span>100</span>
  <span>120</span>
  <span>140</span>
  <span>160</span>
  <span>180</span>
  <span>200</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This one seems to work flawlessly on Chrome + Firefox. Great solution!